# Gitlab runner doesn't start

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

On my instance,

[image]

I added a runner on a Apple Silicon M1, but this runner doesn't start.
That's why I assigned a project to it, with the hope of starting, but I see this

[image]

- But how can I check why is there a red ! ?
- What prevents to start it ?

This is what I did.

**Create docker runner:**

```
docker stop gitlab-runner && docker rm gitlab-runner

docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /Users/Shared/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

register runner:

```
docker run --rm -v /Users/Shared/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image hannesa2/android-ndk:api28_emu \
  --url "http://latitude:8083/" \
  --registration-token "<TOKEN>" \
  --description "M1 pro Android NDK + Emu" \
  --tag-list "android,android-ndk,android-emu" \
  --run-untagged="true" \
  --locked="false" \
  --access-level="not_protected"
```

and I see this in docker log

```
Runtime platform         arch=arm64 os=linux pid=8 revision=4b9e985a version=14.4.0
Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
Running in system-mode.                            

Configuration loaded     builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
ERROR: Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory  builds=0
ERROR: Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory  builds=0
ERROR: Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory  builds=0
ERROR: Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory  builds=0
ERROR: Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory  builds=0
Configuration loaded     builds=0
```

Host comes with this file /Users/Shared/gitlab-runner/config/config.toml

Docker container comes with it too
[image]

Thank you

Comment: The runner is its own binary with its own log files. What are the logs for the runner reporting? What errors are you seeing? If you can provide more information, we can help further.

Comment: @Patrick I updated logging info on client (what I found)

Answer (score 1):

You're starting the runner with `-v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner`. But the registration uses a different path for the volume (`-v /Users/Shared/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner`).

So the actual runner cannot find the config being written by the registration command. You should use the same hostPath for both invocations.

Comment: Now, I run into next error. To give you reputation here for this, I opened the follow up https://stackoverflow.com/q/70094470/1079990