# Gitlab runner doesn't start on Apple M1

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

On my instance,

[image]

I added a runner on a Apple Silicon M1, but this runner doesn't start.
That's why I assigned a project to it, with the hope of starting, but I see this

[image]

- But how can I check why is there a red ! ?
- What prevents to start it ?

This is what I did.

**Create docker runner:**

```
docker stop gitlab-runner && docker rm gitlab-runner

docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /Users/Shared/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

register runner:

```
docker run --rm -v /Users/Shared/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image hannesa2/android-ndk:api28_emu \
  --url "http://latitude:8083/" \
  --registration-token "<TOKEN>" \
  --description "M1 pro Android NDK + Emu" \
  --tag-list "android,android-ndk,android-emu" \
  --run-untagged="true" \
  --locked="false" \
  --access-level="not_protected"
```

and I see this in docker log

```
Runtime platform         arch=arm64 os=linux pid=8 revision=4b9e985a version=14.4.0
Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
Running in system-mode.                            

Configuration loaded     builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden               runner=Jc2yrs_v
ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden               runner=Jc2yrs_v
ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden               runner=Jc2yrs_v
ERROR: Runner http://latitude:8083/Jc2yrs_v8JkJyMJAGUd_ is not healthy and will be disabled!
Configuration loaded     builds=0
```

Thank you

Comment: The `forbidden` message would indicate to me your registration token is not valid or you've potentially misconfigured the server URL.

Comment: There are a few issues that have been filed about runner on M1. See if this comment helps: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28389#note_727265790

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is support on SaaS only, with [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#apple-silicon-m1-gitlab-saas-runners-on-macos-beta) (May 2023):

> ### Apple silicon (M1) GitLab SaaS runners on macOS - Beta
>
> (ony GitLab SaaS Premium or Ultimate)
>
> Mobile DevOps teams can now run their entire CI/CD workflows on Apple silicon (M1)
> [GitLab SaaS runners on macOS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/macos_saas_runner)
> to seamlessly create, test, and deploy applications for the Apple ecosystem.
>
> With up to **three times** the performance of hosted x86-64 macOS Runners,
> you will increase your development team’s velocity in building and deploying applications
> that require macOS in a secure, on-demand GitLab Runner build environment integrated with GitLab CI/CD.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_0/macos-m1-runners.png -- Apple silicon (M1) GitLab SaaS runners on macOS - Beta]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/macos_saas_runner.html#example-gitlab-ciyml-file) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/342848).